# How to only include the used cordova plugins in IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an ios application. I am only using crodova's contact plugin in my application. So want only the contact corodva plugin to be included in my build, and all the other unused plugin has to left out. I would like to find, how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

@syed imty 
First you Download new Version Cordova File.
fot you "iOS" folder and before "www" and copy your "Cordova.js" file

Nothing extra only in  your "www" folder past and Connect with  tag. 
Remove previous "Cordova.js" or "Phonegap.js"

Try This, Cheers.....!